# How to hide 'tag area' in PhpStorm 9 under nav area?

Tags: phpstorm

How exactly we can remove or hide 'tag show' area under of nav area
and above of 'text editors' or remove this hover action to text editor in
phpstorm8 and PhpStorm 9?

I've tried to change hover color and action to the text editor but cant find this property in color schema or settings.

Answer (score 1):

**Settings (Preferences on Mac) | Editor | General | Appearance | Show HTML breadcrumbs**

**NOTE:** you need to re-open editor tab to see the changes.